# MAUI CommunityToolkit and Popup are not closing

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0, maui-community-toolkit

In my `NET8` `MAUI` application, I'm using `CommunityToolkit` and in particular the `Popup` service. I have a page and inject in it the *viewmodel* (in the following example is represented by `vm`). I created a simple *LoadingPopup* like in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/views/popup)

```
<toolkit: Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
          x:Class="MyProject.SimplePopup">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="This is a very important message!" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</toolkit: Popup>
```

In order to update the view every time the page is displayed, I wrote this method

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    await vm.Init();
}
```

In the `Init()` function in the *viewmodel* I get this (partial) code

```
public async Task Init()
{
    if (IsRefreshing)
        return;

    IsRefreshing = true;

    var loadingPopup = new LoadingPopup();
    Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopup(loadingPopup);

    // step 1: doing something

    loadingPopup.Close();
    IsRefreshing = false;
}
```

If the activities in *step 1* are long enough, the *LoadingPopup* is displayed and then closed. If the *step 1* is quick, the *LoadingPopup* is still visible. My gut feeling is the page is not rendered as quickly as *step 1* and then when the page appears, displays a status of the page that is not necessarily the last one.

If I debug the code, the popup should be shown and closed but in reality, it doesn't.

### Update

If I use the *async* method is worst.

```
await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(loadingPopup);
```

The *LoadingPopup* is displayed and the app is waiting for it forever.

Comment: await ShowPopupAsync.

Comment: exactly the same

Comment: You are telling me that when you await it, the program continues to //step 1 line? and then calls close? No. The program should be freezing at that line.

Comment: Here is your question, with different words: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77373199/maui-community-toolkit-raise-an-error-when-close-a-popup. I do not recommend ANY of the answers. Try to listen to what I am saying.

Comment: You need ASYNC. You are firing something, and then immediately trying to close it. You have to await something. If not for popup dismissal, then at least for the popup to show. The build-in Task is for the dismissal. This is very common flow. If you want to await opening, then you need to do your own task. Or some sort of notification from the popup that it is opened. Or a flag. Whatever you pick.

Answer (score 0):

You open the popup, and wait for it to be opened:

```
private async void ContentPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Application.Current.MainPage.ShowPopupAsync(new SimplePopup());
}
```

This will make you stop at this line. The task is only completed, when the popup is dismissed, so we have to close it from the other side:

```
private async void Popup_Opened(object sender, CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.PopupOpenedEventArgs e)
{
    await MyTask();
    this.Close();
}
```

Now, this is only a concept I tried to explain in the comment. I am not suggesting filling your code with async voids. I am not telling you to slap those events and write business logic in your Page code. Or to write separate Popup for each task. Ideally you should be passing the task, and all those events should be Commands in the ViewModels, that you bound with EventToCommand behaviors.